# Is it possible to synchonize my iPod with iTunes on one computer and drag-drop ad-hoc files on another?

Tags: ipod, itunes, ipod-touch

I have iTunes installed on both my work and home computer. At home I want to keep it synchronized with my extensive library of music ripped from CDs, but for large files like videos and podcasts I like to download them at work where I have better bandwidth.

I'd like to be able to keep just my music files synchronized with the iPod from my home computer, but still be able to drag-drop a few ad-hoc podcasts/videos downloaded on my work computer onto the device (iPod touch). No synchronization with iTunes on my work computer is desired/required.

It seems like this would be a simple operation, but all of my attempts have resulted in wiping out large portions of the content from the device.

Any advice on how to make this work, or whether it is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I know it was possible with older iPods, not sure about touches though. If you have it jailbroken, you can SSH into the device and store your files that way. You have to have WiFi access in both locations though. That's the simplest way I can think of, sadly lol.

[Here's](http://tomstechjournal.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-jailbreak-iphone-3g.html) how to jailbreak. And [here's](http://www.simonblog.com/2009/05/17/how-to-use-ssh-to-transfer-file-on-iphone/) how to SSH. [Other SSH info.](http://cydia.saurik.com/copying.html)

Hope this helps!

-Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need Sharepod - http://getsharepod.com

Download and install it on your work machine. When you want to drag and drop files, connect your iPod, close iTunes and start sharepod.

Do remember that if you sync your iPod with your home machine, then all your "extra" files from your office will go away. One solution is to configure your iTunes at home to sync only music and not videos.